# Image source from state attribute

Tags: image, react-native

So I have this database:

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://i.imgur.com/5UzmND6.png",
    "idEquipo": 4
  },
  {
    "url": "https://i.imgur.com/yNj4w3b.jpg",
    "idEquipo": 3
  },
  {
    "url": "https://i.imgur.com/410yDrl.png",
    "idEquipo": 1
  },
  {
    "url": "https://i.imgur.com/Qv4S7p7.png",
    "idEquipo": 2
  },
  {
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RKsZuCqlheKnuu5yf-6MLoct_SDqX6we/view",
    "idEquipo": 5
  }
]
```

I want to use the state "imagen" as my image source.

This is my fetch:

```
getImagenes(id) {
    fetch(Global.url + "Imagenes?idEquipo=" + id)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          imagen: res,
          isLoading: false,
        });
      });
  }
```

To be clear, fetch(Global.url + "Imagenes?idEquipo=" + id) returns this:

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://i.imgur.com/410yDrl.png",
    "idEquipo": 1
  }
]
```

So I want to get access to the url and use it as the source of my image.

This is my code, but it doesnt work. It's the first time I use uri, i'm a student.

```
<View style={styles.app_LogoContainer}>
      <Image source={{uri: this.state.imagen.url}} 
      style={styles.image}></Image>
</View>
```

How can I do this? Thanks for the help

Comment: I get an error that says that this.state.imagen.url is null. This makes me think  that the fetch never gets done but it doesnt make sense as I have the exact same code with another url and it works

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me that you have an object or an array with a single item. Did you try with `imagen[0].url`?

Comment: It says it's null :/